# Finding the set of solutions

Tags: calculus

Kindly asking to find the set of possible solutions if they exist of the equation $$\lfloor x+\lfloor x+\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor+3\lfloor x\rfloor=18$$ Of course I have 4 intervals as choices:

> 1. $[\frac{5}{2}, \frac{7}{2})$
> 2. $[3, 5)\smallsetminus \{4\}$
> 3. $[3, 4)$
> 4. $\emptyset$

$\lfloor x\rfloor$ is largest integer not greater than $x$. Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems to me that $x=3$ is a solution, while $x=5/2$ is not. This should exclude 1 and 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: show that if $n$ is an integer, and $r$ is any real number, then
$$\lfloor r+n\rfloor=\lfloor r\rfloor+n.$$
Apply this to the expression $\lfloor x+\lfloor x+\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor$.

Comment: I should have considered that [r+n]=[r]+n. Thank you